# Examples of use of each verb form

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, tiempos-verbales

I understand that some of these forms are obsolete, but I would like to see examples for each one of them (how they were used before). Also point out which forms are used now instead of the old ones. Here are the examples that I've come up with so far. Maybe there are mistakes somewhere, corrections are welcome.

### Indicativo.

#### Presente.

- Trabaja hoy.
- Trabaja cada día.

#### Imperfecto.

- Trabajaba cada día la semana pasada.
- El trabajaba cuando ella entró.

#### Pretérito perfecto simple.

- Trabajó ayer.

#### Futuro

- Trabajará mañana.

#### Pretérito perfecto compuesto

- Ya ha trabajado hoy.

#### Pretérito pluscuamperfecto

- Se encontró con su amigo con quien había trabajado antes.
- Ella dijo que el había trabajado cada día la semana pasada.

#### Pretérito anterior

- hubo trabajado

#### Futuro perfecto

- Habrá trabajado con su amigo por el fin de semana.

---

### Subjuntivo

#### Presente

- Ella se alegra de que él trabaje.
- Tiene un amigo que trabaje mucho.

#### Imperfecto.

- Ella le aconsejó que trabajara con su amigo.
- Si trabajara menos pudiera ser el hombre más feliz.

#### Pretérito perfecto simple.

- trabajase

#### Futuro

- trabajaré

#### Pretérito perfecto compuesto

- haya trabajado

#### Pretérito pluscuamperfecto

- hubiera trabajado

#### Pretérito anterior

- hubiese trabajado

#### Futuro perfecto

- hubiere trabajado.

### Condicional.

#### Condicional.

- Ella dijo que él trabajaría mañana.
- Trabajaría con su amigo pero no tiene tiempo.
- Si tuvieras tiempo trabajarías con él.

#### Condicional perfecto.

- Ella dijo que él habría trabajado con su amigo por el fin de semana.
- Habría trabajado con su amigo por el fin de semana pero el amigo se había puesto enfermo.

---

### Imperativo.

#### Afirmativo.

- Trabaja con su amigo.

#### Negativo.

- No trabajes con él.

Comment: Imperfecto de subjuntivo tiene un error. Con ese ejemplo todo el mundo usaría "podría". Un ejemplo con "pudiese" sería: "Tendría que trabajar muchas menos horas para que pudiera ser un hombre más feliz".

Comment: Also, future subjunctive is *trabajare*, not *trabajaré*.

Answer (score 3):

## Indicativo

### Presente

> Tiene un amigo que **trabaja** mucho.
>
> **Trabajas** demasiado.

### Pretérito imperfecto

> Cuando yo **trabajaba** en esa empresa, no había horario intensivo.
>
> Nos conocimos cuando **trabajábamos** en la panadería.

### Pretérito perfecto simple

> **Trabajé** cada día la semana pasada.
>
> Él **trabajó** ayer.

### Futuro simple

> Este fin de semana **trabajaré** solo el sábado.
>
> **Trabajará** mañana.

### Pretérito perfecto compuesto

> **He trabajado** demasiado este mes.
>
> ¿**Has trabajado** alguna vez con esta aplicación?

### Pretérito pluscuamperfecto

> Ella dijo que él **había trabajado** cada día la semana pasada.
>
> Te pregunté si **habías trabajado** con él y me mentiste.

### Pretérito anterior (en desuso)

> Cuando **hube trabajado** suficiente, me fui.

Currently replaced by the **pretérito pluscuamperfecto** or **pretérito perfecto simple** tenses:

> En cuanto **trabajé** suficiente, me fui.

### Futuro perfecto

> Cuando tú te jubiles, yo **habré trabajado** sólo diez años.
>
> Contando el próximo sábado, **habrá trabajado** todos los fines de semana de este mes.

---

---

## Subjuntivo

### Presente

> Que ella **trabaje** más horas dependerá del sueldo.
>
> Ella se alegra de que él **trabaje**.

### Pretérito perfecto

> Que **hayas trabajado** de camarero no quiere decir que sepas servir.
>
> ¡Ojala **haya trabajado**!

### Pretérito imperfecto

> Tenían pensado casarse en cuanto **trabajasen** los dos.

### Pretérito pluscuamperfecto

> Si **hubiese trabajado** más, le habrían subido el sueldo.
>
> Si **hubiésemos trabajado** mejor, habrían comprado mejor equipamiento.

### Futuro simple (en desuso)

> Aquellos que **trabajaren** el fin de semana, serán premiados con días libres.
>
> Quien **trabajare** de menos, será castigado con la suspensión de empleo y sueldo.

Currently mostly used only in legal texts and replaced by the **presente** tense:

> Aquellos que **trabajen** el fin de semana, serán premiados con días libres.

### Futuro perfecto (en desuso)

> Los que **hubieren trabajado** el fin de semana, serán premiados con días libres.
>
> Cuando el empleado **hubiere trabajado** tres meses, el período de prueba habrá finalizado.

As with the previous tense, it's mostly used only in legal texts and replaced by the **pretérito perfecto** tense:

> Cuando el empleado **haya trabajado** tres meses, el período de prueba habrá finalizado.

---

---

## Condicional

### Condicional simple

> Pedro **trabajaría** más si le subiesen el sueldo.
>
> Con mejor equipamiento, **trabajaríamos** mucho mejor.

### Condicional perfecto

> Si le hubiesen subido el sueldo, Pedro **habría trabajado** mejor y no le hubiesen despedido.
>
> **Habríamos trabajado** más si hubiésemos tenido mejor equipamiento.

---

---

## Imperativo

### Afirmativo

> **Trabajad** más y cobraréis más.
>
> ¡**Trabaja**!

### Negativo

> **No trabajéis** más, que no vais a cobrar más.
>
> ¡**No trabajes**!

Answer (score 0):

### Indicativo

Pretérito anterior.
      -hubo trabajado-

Example: Someone has two tasks to do, but not time to complete them both. Lets say that he decides to work just two hours on each

> Cuando **hubo trabajado** por dos horas en la primera tarea, pasó a la segunda.

### Subjuntivo

Pretérito perfecto simple.
      -trabajase-

> Le contraté para que **trabajase** quitando las hierbas de mi jardín.

Futuro.
      -trabajare-
(almost never used except in legal writings)

> Quien no **trabajare** satisfactoriamente será amonestado.

Current usage would be present subjunctive:

> Quien no **trabaje** satisfactoriamente será amonestado.

Pretérito perfecto compuesto.
      -haya trabajado-

> Le pagaré un 10% más a aquel que **haya trabajado** barriendo el suelo

Pretérito pluscuamperfecto.
      -hubiese trabajado- -hubiera trabajado-

> (Al final del día) Si alguien **hubiera/hubiese trabajado** hoy barriendo el suelo habría cobrado un 10% más

Futuro perfecto.
      -hubiere trabajado- 
(almost never used except in legal writings)

> (Al comienzo del día) Al final del día de hoy, en caso de que alguien **hubiere trabajado** barriendo el suelo, a esa persona se le pagará un 10% más.

Current usage would be Pretérito perfecto compuesto:

> Al final del día de hoy, en caso de que alguien **haya trabajado** barriendo el suelo, a esa persona se le pagará un 10% más.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there are two *pretérito pluscuamperfectos*. The one you have is the compuesto form. There is also a simple form which is identical to the -ra form of the past imperfect subjunctive.